# How to get all request.querystring one by one

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, web-config

This is my code and in this code i got request.querystring("id") eg. www.site.com/q

but i need all request.querystring by separate name eg. www.site.com/q1/q2/q3/q4

how do i set all request.querystring name and got data via this we.config ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="DeduplicateSlashes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)//(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="CleanRouting" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="?id={R:0}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<!-- Double escaping is needed for URLs with '+', e.g. for the account page for a username with a space. -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want in the web.config, but this will get you all of the querystring pairs:

```
Dim item
For each item in Request.Form
    Response.Write "Name: " & item & " Value= " & Request(item)
Next
```

Comment: in this code    <action type="Rewrite" url="?id={R:0}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" /> id is a default 1st query name how do i set next query name ?

Comment: for example url: www.site.com/a (a is id value) but i need www.site.com/a/b (how to set b's query name ?)

Comment: Are you talking about the URL Rewrite module in IIS (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) - to do what you are asking, you won't do it in ASP code, you set it up in IIS

Comment: ya but how to write the code lines in this web.config

Comment: to set the next query name, you change that to `<action type="Rewrite" url="?id={R:0}&amp;nextvalue={R:1}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />` just building out the string with {R:n}, incrementing n for each of the next values